# disabling modal popup in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I want to create a custom message without using the modal popup in jqgrid. Is there a way to disable it? Or is there a way to change the contents of the modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific? If you want your own modal dialog, you could just add an event handler (on an Edit button, for example) that when fired will open your own custom dialog. You can use the jQuery UI dialog for this purpose, and just have it open to your own custom form.

**Update**
After inspecting the jqGrid source code, `info_dialog` is the function that is used to display this particular dialog. There is a separate call to display the "Loading..." popup. Offhand there does not seem to be a simple way to disable `info_dialog`. However, you could modify the jqGrid source to accomplish what you need. You could either:

- Return immediately from `info_dialog` - which may be extreme because it could report other errors you need - or,
- Find and comment out the call that is displaying this particular ajax error. There is some trial-and-error involved, but with only 18 calls to this function it will not take you long to track down. In fact, start by commenting out this instance, since it is called from the `error` function of an ajax call:

  `info_dialog(a.jgrid.errors.errcap,e.status+" : "+e.statusText+"<br/>"+u,a.jgrid.edit.bClose);`

Obviously such a modification is a last resort, but once it works you might consider rolling a patch for the jqGrid team to disable the alert.

Comment: jqgrid uses a default popup for alerts, that's what I want to remove

Comment: You mean the one that says "loading", for example?

Comment: yes. and the one that appears whenever a server request failed (I successfully captured the ajaxError event and had my custom message set up, but the modal dialog also appears, which says Error: 500 and the corresponding message

Answer (score 0):

Search for **div.loadingui div.msgbox { ... }** somewhere in css files. I think editing this css class will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is out of the topic, but have you tried SlickGrid https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/examples

Comment: Nice grid, but are you suggesting he start from scratch just because he is having trouble displaying a custom message box?

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the z-index of modal popup on runtime once you can access to it you can do any customization

```
editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 10,

                            dataEvents: [
                          { type: 'keypress',
                              fn: function (e) {
                                  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                      **$("#info_dialog").css('z-index', '100000');**
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                       ]


                        } }
```

Also, if you can do it on another place if you have server response such as error

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, aData) {
                    currentRow = rowid;
                    if (rowid && rowid !== lastsel) {
                        if (lastsel) jQuery('#ppGrid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        $("#ppGrid").jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, null, null, null, {}, reload,OnError);
                        lastsel = rowid;
                    }
                    else if (rowid && rowid === lastsel)
                    { $("#ppGrid").jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, null, null, null, {}, reload,OnError); }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. you can make visible property to false [`$("#info_dialog").visible(false);`] of the modal box, and you can call what ever your custom modal box.

```
editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validate_edit }


function validate_edit(posdata, colName) {
            var message = "";
            if (posdata != '' && $.isNumeric(posdata))
                return [true, ""];

            if (posdata == '')
                message = colName + " field is required"
            if (!$.isNumeric(posdata))
                message = posdata + " is not a number";

            alert(message);

            $("#info_dialog").visible(false);

            return [false, ""];
        }
```