# What is "info_dialog" Method in Visual Studio 2010 Javascript AutoComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-ajax, message

When editing javascript in VS2010, the dropdown autocomplete list shows a method called `info_dialog` - i dont have this method in any of my javascript and cant seem to find out where it comes from or what it does?

Does anyone know? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

`info_dialog` is a method used by jqGrid to display messages. It can also be used by external code and has the ability to be shown modally as well.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115488/disabling-modal-popup-in-jqgrid)